# Prevent audio quality degradation when microphone in use?

Tags: macos, audio, microphone

I googled and although the top result is for [Windows](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/sound-quality-drop-when-microphone-is-activated/cf72c17e-8b7d-4d87-8ec9-666e8f9ba31e), it describes my exact problem: namely, when the microphone is in use, audio quality becomes horrible.

#### Example

I'm on a coworking session (where participants have webcams on and can see eachother for a fixed period of time, to encourage focus, a bit like pomodoro technique), anyway, this means the mic is being accessed by the browser (although it's muted for most the session), and hence when I play music, the quality is awful.

#### Question

How do I prevent the drop in audio quality when the mic is in use?

Notes:

- I'm using regular (non-apple) bluetooth headphones, in case that's relevant
- I'm not totally sure why this happens; i.e. whether it's macOS thing, a 'browser' setting, or something controlled by a setting/standard on the hardware itself.

Comment: You can't This is part of Apple's implementation of  Bluetooth . See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/395716/237 foir similar issue. There should be a direct duplicate here but I can't find it.

Comment: This is the same as the correct answer given lower down the page on that MS question. The codec changes when the mic is enabled - the bandwidth isn't sufficient to cope with *both* high-quality stereo *and* the mic, so the headset speakers drop to a more data-efficient codec.

Comment: Interesting. Is there any 'hack' to perhaps force the mic to be poor quality to allow the audio to remain high quality, or even some external tool/command to limit or throttle mic throughput?

Comment: I doubt it. PC 'gaming headsets' get around it by not using Bluetooth, they use something 'a bit like WiFi' on 2.4GHz. [I've never investigated exactly how it's done, sorry]